# Problem Exporting runnable jar file in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, swt

I am hoping someone can help me, I am at my wits end with this problem.
my code compiles and runs, I cannot export the code to a runnable jar file.
I can export it on a different computer and it works fine.
My eclipse gives the following error as soon as I press export to runnable jar file

[image: the error]

```
The error log contains.
```

[image: error1]
[image: error2]
[image: error3]
[image: error4]

I am at my wits end, Any help or assistance is appreciated. This is my first time posting here. Sorry if my formatting is off or if this is in the wrong location.

Comment: Your Eclipse is one release behind. Does it work with the current version? Please keep in mind, if you have a `module-info.java` file and dependencies, you cannot export it to a _Runnable JAR_.

Comment: Deploying an SWT application is an  difficult issue. At the one hand there are some eclipse dependencies and (that's the urgly part) at the other hand there are some OS dependent libs. Thats why you have to create a kind of bundle for every OS you want to support. I had done this years ago, but I don't know how it has to be done properly now, sorry!

Comment: The program runs and exports from eclipse on a different computer - I will update my version of eclipse and see if that helps.

Comment: Updated Eclipse, still the same issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying to fix this multiple times, I finally resolved the issue. by doing the following:
I removed eclipse.
reinstalled eclipse.
removed the metadata folder in my workspace.
reinstalled eclipse
etc

It now works fine. I think it was some sort of corruption of the metadata folder. I am updating this to assist anyone else that might experience this strange issue.

Comment: **Never ever delete the `.metadata` folder!** That's a hoax spread on Stack Overflow that **can cause harm**. If running Eclipse with `-clean` does not help, use a fresh workspace, but never ever delete `.metadata` folder.